# Testing whether a seasonal dip in a time series this year is abnormal compared to previous years

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, anova, f-test

Let's say I have sales data for each month of the year for the last few years. Sales tend to dip in the summer, and I want to determine if the dip this year (or for a given month) is abnormal.

```
   month   2014     2015     2016
       1   7775     8454     7700
       2  12122    16229    20978
       3  11631    16308    21051
       4  11840    16004    21045
       5  12108    16800    21807
    ...
```

Would an F-test/ANOVA be appropriate for this kind of year-over-year data? If not, what might be?

Comment: You need to adjust for autocorrelation

Comment: The previous title ("Hypothesis testing for year-over-year data") was rather vague - it could have applied to almost any question about hypothesis tests for time series - and I don't think it captured the essence of your question. I have edited to make the title more specific - feel free to edit and improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fit a model from seasonal ARIMA family. Estimate the residual for a month of interest, and compare it to the error variance. This will give you an idea of whether the "dip" was larger than "normal".